# Is this too opinion-based?

Tags: discussion

Question: [Oil pan and timing cover gaskets replacement worth it?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/61081/oil-pan-and-timing-cover-gaskets-replacement-worth-it)

It's asking whether a replacement on his specific car is worth it, given mileage and type.  It seems a bit opinion-based to me, and the current answer is just a "yes, it's worth it; your car can last quite a while longer."  On the one hand, that seems very subjective -- what's a while longer?  On the other hand, it would be possible to make a good "no, it's not worth it" case, should there be one, where the argument was that it would cost (significantly) more to keep it than to get a different car.  That would seem to be objective.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this question is opinion based, that's why I answered it as a comment. I saw other people answering in comments too instead of writing answer. So I think others are thinking the same.